# What steps must be performed to get a applet which can work with File?

Tags: java, file, jar, policy, signed-applet

I have an applet with a function which returns a List of all Netdrives if this function is called by javascript.

Currently I get a permission denied exception. Google told me: I have to sign it and create a policy file. But I am not getting forward.

Could you tell me the steps, how to get this working?

Greetings and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the applet, before it gets permission to access files:
See http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html

or this (newer): http://www.entrust.net/ssl-resources/pdf/ECS_Java_Code_Signing_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

> I have an applet with a function which returns a List of all Netdrives if this function is called by javascript.
>
> Currently I get a permission denied exception. Google told me: I have to sign it..

Correct.

> ..and create a policy file. ..

Redundant if the signed applet code is accepted by the end user when prompted.

> But I am not getting forward.

The missing ingredient is that you probably need to wrap those calls in an [AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged%28java.security.PrivilegedAction%29).  This is caused by the interaction with JS.